# Cannot Install 'rgl' package in R

Tags: r, windows, rgl

I am using R version 4.1.3.
I get the following:

```
** installing *source* package 'rgl' ...
** package 'rgl' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
*** arch - i386
Makevars.win:33: *** missing separator.  Stop.
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rgl'*
```

Below is output of sessionInfo:

```
    R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.3 tools_4.1.3
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Questions about installing R packages from source require much more complete documentation of your setup and target installation.

Comment: Please add the output from `sessionInfo()` (please into a [code block]), and include which version of Rtools is installed on your system.

Comment: Thank you, both. I have edited to include sessionInfo output. I don't know how to check RTools version. Didn't have any luck Googling this.

Comment: Rtools is something that _you_ had to install yourself, it is not an R package and is installed separately from R and RStudio (if you're using that). Look on your `C:\ ` directory for a directory named `C:\Rtools...`, that's a good start. You can also go through the OS to see what apps are installed: press the `Win` key, start typing "Apps", and it should show you (among possibly others) "Add or remove programs" (which we're not going to do, but it allows us to see what is installed).

Comment: Interesting...I do indeed have a folder for it, Rtools40, but it doesn't show up as an app as you suggested. I think I'll just delete this folder and "re"-install Rtools.

Comment: So I just re-installed Rtools4.0 to no avail.

Comment: I suspect this is either a misconfiguration (outside of my knowledge) or a bug in `rgl`'s makefile. It might be necessary to reach out to the author (perhaps a [new issue](https://github.com/dmurdoch/rgl/issues/new/choose)) for specific help. You will need to provide more information: I'd start with all of the console text including and after `install.packages("rgl")` (please add that here, too), and it might be useful for the author if you include the contents of the erring `Makevars.win` file (since it is auto-generated during compiling). Good luck!

Comment: What is the command you use to install the package?

Comment: May not need the entire Makefile. If that is the real source of the problem, the problem is in line 33 according to the error message. On the other hand, seems likely that the version numbers of Rtools, R, rgl will reveal a mismatch of compiler, R and package.

Comment: Thank you all. do believe it has something to do with a mismatch, so I'll try to install the correct version of the package. Currently, I clicked the RStudio Packages install button, so I didn't type any command.

Comment: It's a lot easier to install a binary of the package rather than compiling from source.  But binaries are not available for R 4.1.x any more, so your best bet is to update to a current R version.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you all for your help, except for user IRTFM.